# python read variables in .bin files

Tags: python, binary

This is the file description.

```
DSET ^AHI8_L2MOA.I2016001.000000.v210.bin
TITLE AHI8_L2MOA.I2016001.000000.v210.bin
*OPTIONS yrev little_endian
UNDEF -999999.0
XDEF         3425 linear 1 1
YDEF         1721 linear 1 1
ZDEF           10 linear 1 1
TDEF 1 linear 00:00Z01JAN2016 10mn
VARS       11
mlon 0 99 Longitude (deg)
mlat 0 99 Latitude  (deg)
qflg 0 99 QA flag
mtim 0 99 Measurement time (hours)
snza 0 99 Sensor zenith  angle (deg)
snaa 0 99 Sensor azimuth angle (deg)
soza 0 99 Solar zenith angle (deg)
soaa 0 99 Solar azimuth angle (deg)
selv 0 99 Surface elevation (m)
rada 6 99 Albedo (%), 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

How to use python to read the variable 'rada' in this file? I want to assign it value to numpy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `open()` and `read()` would be a start...

Comment: _Which_ variable? And what did you try?

Comment: @DYZ  the variable `rada`

Answer (score -1):

Briefly, you want to iterate through the file line by line and parse the values

```
with open('data.bin') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split() # split the line on whitespace
        if parts[0] == 'mlon': # whatever variable you want to process
            a = int(parts[1]) # convert next two params from strings to integers
            b = int(parts[2])
            desc = ' '.join(parts[2:]) # join the rest back together as the description
            print(a, b, desc)
```

Comment: I'm interested in the reason this attracted a downvote?